# Volcar info de un csv nuevo a dataframe pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataset

Estoy construyendo un dataset para un proyecto, para ello, primero proceso una serie de datos y escribo un fichero csv, más o menos de esta forma:

```
csvObj = open("dataset.csv", "w", encoding="utf-8")
csvWriter = csv.writer(csvObj, lineterminator="\n")
csvWriter.writerow(cabecera) #Escritura cabecera
csvWriter ... ***escribo el resto de datos***
```

Luego, en otro script leo con pandas el csv generado y realizo las modificaciones pertinentes:

```
dataframe = pandas.read_csv("dataset.csv")
#Modificaciones y tal
dataframe.to_csv("dataset.csv")
```

Ahora bien, yo quiero realizar estas dos acciones en el mismo script sin tener que guardar un primer csv para luego leerlo, había probado con `dataframe = pd.read_csv(csvObj)` pero claro, falla.

¿Cómo debería hacerlo?

Comment: osea ya no quieres hacer la primera operacion de guardar datos, si no que quieres operar y luego guardar el resultado, verdad?

Comment: @Christian justo, quiero crear mis datos, hacer las operaciones que hago luego con el dataset y guardarlo de una vez, sin dos pasos

Comment: Listo publique una respuesta, creo que te refieres a eso, no hice muchas operaciones ya que no muestras los datos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bueno lo que quieres hacer es, en resumen, generar un *DataFrame*, ya que con el se puede realizar distintas operaciones, como si de un *.csv* o *.xlsl* se tratase, para ello *pandas* nos permite crear *DataFrames* de varias formas.

**Creando con diccionarios**

```py
import pandas as pd


#especificamos las columnas que tendra
columnas = ['c1','c2','c3']
#especificamos los datos
data = {'c1':'info1','c2':'info1','c3':10}

#generamos nuestro DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns =columnas)

#luego ya podemos hacer cualquier operacion
#por ejemplo seleccionamos la columna c1
c1 = df['c1'] #nos trae todos los datos de la columna
```

**creando con listas**

```py
import pandas as pd

#especificamos los datos
data = [['info1','info2','info3'],['info1.1','info2.1',20]]

#especificamos las columnas
columnas = ['c1', 'c2', 'c3']
#generamos nuestro DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns =columnas)

#luego ya podemos hacer cualquier operacion
#por ejemplo seleccionamos la columna c1
c1 = df['c1'] #nos trae todos los datos de la columna
```

Luego de haber realizado las operaciones necesarias lo guardamos como `.csv`

```py
df.to_csv("dataset.csv")
```

Comment: No era exactamente lo que buscaba, quizá me he expresado mal, pero si que me ha servido para resolverlo, en cuanto lo aplique y lo tenga limpio lo pondré. Muchas gracias

Comment: Bueno yo creo que si es a lo que te refieres, pero que bueno que te haya ayudado, si tienes otra duda o problema no dudes en hacer tu pregunta :)